# Loop through multiple dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

Python novice here and I am looking for a concise way to write my program. I want to read multiple csv files and clean them for outliers and after that I want to normalize the columns and then create a combined dataset from the normalized columns. The input csv file has many columns and I want to normalize all the columns. Here in the code I have written an example for 2 columns.

the code i wrote works fine, but its tedious and cumbersome. I have it written for 3 datasets. In reality I could be looking at a lot more. Any help on how to loop this and make it look concise?  Thanks

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    gr_P10 = 40
    gr_P50 = 65
    gr_P90 = 90
    rt_P10 = 10
    rt_P50 = 25
    rt_P90 = 50

    def get_quantiles(input_log):
      p10_log = np.percentile(input_log, 10)
      p50_log = np.percentile(input_log, 50)
      p90_log = np.percentile(input_log, 90)
    return p10_log, p50_log, p90_log

    def normalize(input_log, x_90, x_50, x_10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log):
      mmin = (x_50-x_10)/(p50_log-p10_log)
      mmax = (x_90-x_50)/(p90_log-p50_log)
      if (input_log < p50_log ):
        output_log = x_50 +(mmin*(input_log-p50_log))
      else:
        output_log = x_50 +(mmax*(input_log-p50_log))
    return output_log

# Read data and removing outliers
#Data1
a = pd.read_csv('Data1.csv')
zscore = np.abs(stats.zscore(a))
a = a[(zscore < 3).all(axis=1)]
#Data2
b = pd.read_csv('Data2.csv')
zscore = np.abs(stats.zscore(b))
b = b[(zscore < 3).all(axis=1)]
#Data3
c = pd.read_csv('Data3.csv')
zscore = np.abs(stats.zscore(c))
c = c[(zscore < 3).all(axis=1)]
# Normalizing Data
# Normalizing Data1
p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(a['GR'])
a['GR_NORM'] = a.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['GR'],gr_P90, gr_P50, gr_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)

p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(a['RT'])
a['RT_NORM'] = a.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['RT'],rt_P90, rt_P50, rt_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)
# Normalizing Data2
p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(b['GR'])
b['GR_NORM'] = b.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['GR'],gr_P90, gr_P50, gr_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)

p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(b['RT'])
b['RT_NORM'] = b.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['RT'],rt_P90, rt_P50, rt_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)
# Normalizing Data3
p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(c['GR'])
c['GR_NORM'] = c.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['GR'],gr_P90, gr_P50, gr_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)

p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(c['RT'])
c['RT_NORM'] = c.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['RT'],rt_P90, rt_P50, rt_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)
# Forming new combined dataset with normalized values
new_a = a['GR_NORM','RT_NORM'].copy()
new_b = b['GR_NORM','RT_NORM'].copy()
new_c = c['GR_NORM','RT_NORM'].copy()
new_dataset = pd.concat([new_a,new_b, new_c], ignore_index= True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use functions more to get rid of duplicate code. Try replacing the second half with something like this:

```
# Read data and removing outliers
#Data1

def read_data(data):
    a = pd.read_csv(data)
    zscore = np.abs(stats.zscore(a))
    a = a[(zscore < 3).all(axis=1)]

    #Normalizing Data
    p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(a['GR'])
    a['GR_NORM'] = a.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['GR'],gr_P90, gr_P50, gr_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)

    p10_log, p50_log, p90_log = get_quantiles(a['RT'])
    a['RT_NORM'] = a.apply(lambda x: normalize(x['RT'],rt_P90, rt_P50, rt_P10, p90_log, p50_log, p10_log ), axis =1)

    return a['GR_NORM','RT_NORM'].copy()


data = ['Data1.csv','Data2.csv','Data3.csv']

new_dataset = pd.DataFrame()

for x in data:
    new_dataset = new_dataset.append(read_data(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm overlooking something, you can just write a function for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
N_files = 3
for i in range(1, N_files):
    a = pd.read_csv(f"Data{i}.csv")  #this will loop through open all your files
```